# File name as parameter in SQL LOADER

Tags: oracle, shell, sql-loader

I have this scenario :

In my working directory i have a **sh** script , **ctl** file and **input file** , 
when i try to launch the shell script with the input parameter (filename.txt):

```
mysh.sh filename.txt
```

i get this error :

```
SQL*Loader-500: Unable to open file (filename.txt)
SQL*Loader-553: file not found
SQL*Loader-509: System error: No such file or directory
SQL*Loader-2026: the load was aborted because SQL Loader cannot continue.
```

Note : **All my objects (files and directory has 777 permissions )**

If i launch the shell script with the full path to the input file , everything works fine

```
mysh.sh fullpathtofile/filename.txt
```

My question is : **why it is not working when i insert only the file name as input parameter?**

Part of conent of my sh file :

```
!/usr/bin/sh
sqlldr $USER/$PASSWD control=pathtofile data=$1  log=pathtofile  bad=pathtofile
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the code in `mysh.sh`

Comment: i did rightnow, as i said above , it works fine if i insert the full path of the input file . thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

as mysh.sh shell script and input file filename.txt are placed in same location, shell script is able to locate the file(won't work if is in other path). But sqlldr is a oracle tool which is installed in different location so you are supposed to pass full path to locate a file.